# Приведение БД к НФ

Tags: mysql, sql

Имеется три таблицы:

City

```
+----+--------+-----------+------------+
| id |  name  | region_id | country_id |
+----+--------+-----------+------------+
| 1  | Город1 |     2     |      1     |
+----+--------+-----------+------------+
| 2  | Город2 |     1     |      1     |
+----+--------+-----------+------------+
| 3  | Город3 |     3     |      2     |
+----+--------+-----------+------------+
```

Region

```
+----+----------+------------+
| id |   name   | country_id |
+----+----------+------------+
|  1 | Регион1  |     1      |
+----+----------+------------+
|  2 | Регион2  |     1      |
+----+----------+------------+
|  3 | Регион3  |     3      |
+----+----------+------------+
```

Country

```
+----+---------+
| id |  name   |
+----+---------+
| 1  | Страна1 |
+----+---------+
| 2  | Страна2 |
+----+---------+
```

В описанной архитектуре поле `country_id` избыточно — как в самом городе, так и в регионе города, порождает потенциальные коллизии, когда город1 принадлежит стране1 и находится в регионе1, принадлежащем стране2. Можно было бы удалить `country_id` в таблице `city` и брать его из привязанной таблицы `Region`, но не каждый город имеет регион. Что будет лучшим решением описанной проблемы, как уйти от потенциальных коллизий и избыточности информации?

Comment: Слить регионы и страны в одну таблицу. добавив в нее поле parent_id, которое у регионов будет указывать на страну. У стран оно NULL. После этого у городов остается единственная id, которая может быть как регионом так и страной. плюс появляется возможность делать более чем двухуровневую иерархию (правда в MySQL с ней работать будет не удобно)

Comment: Я бы вообще ратовал за одну таблицу. Сущность-то одна - субъект административно-территориального деления.

Answer (score 0):

Если мы работаем с древовидной структурой переменной длины, то единственный способ - хранить все данные в одной таблице с полем, указывающим тип и ссылкой на родителя.

В вашем ограниченном примере, конечно, можно сделать добавить ограничение, чтобы в таблице city из двух полей  (region_id, country_id) всегда было заполнено строго одно.

Но в России бывают ситуации когда город иерархически находится внутри другого города.